# sharepoint 2013 C# update people or group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, c-sharp

I have a requirement to move few of the items from Calendar A to Calendar B. How do I copy the below column values from A to B using C#?

Attendees, Free/Busy, Resources, CheckDoubleBooking, Category

Does creating variables of type "var" for these columns help?
Or is there a way I can directly assign it to the new item of Calendar B

Answer (score 1):

As you are using SharePoint Online, so instead of using C# you can use CSOM to copy data from one calendar to another calendar. Simply you can get data from Calendar A and then Add a new Item in Calendar B using same data.

You can refer to below link for basic operations of CSOM:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

This link will help you to get list item/event from Calendar A and create a new new item/event in calendar B. Hope this will help you.